# PHP, MYSQL, & RAM?

Tags: mysql, php, memory

My computer:
Windows Vista Basic, Intel Core 2 Duo 2.8GHZ, 4GB memory. Task manager shows 1.61GB memory currently being used.

Currently I can insert anywhere from 10k to 15k rows (<1kb/row) per second. If i had an actual server like this https://www.servint.net/order.php?pkg=27 with 8gb of ram and quad cores of 2.5GHz would I be able to double my amount of inserts or triple them maybe? If I was using this as purely a mysql db server would i set it up any differently than I would a regular server?

Basically I want to know what factors enable you to increase the amount of inserts you can do per second.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to at least double, but .. judging by the current stats you're listing, I don't think RAM is even your biggest problem. You should be more interested in the I/O speeds of the HDD.

Comment: Well my computer is 7200rpm, but on their site it says it's a raid1, what is that, and how much will it increase the I/O (in and out?)

Comment: 7200rpm should be ok, but to be specific, I meant the speeds of the actual I/O operations themselves. Take a look at how much MB/sec can be written to the disk, then you should be able to estimate (based on the average size of your rows) how many rows you can write per second

Comment: Also I'm not 100% sure on the RAID differences .. but they don't 'standardize' things like throughput, that is something dependent on the disk + bus. It's also a common statistic that should be listed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably schema changes will do more for you than beefy hardware if you really need to do 15K inserts per second.

As for hardware, as Matt said IO operations are what you want (but that's not the same as the MB/s stat listed for drives).  15000 RPM scsi disks are what you want in raid 1 or raid 10 configuration (RAID 5 and 6 will be significantly slower for database ops).  The speed you're interested in most is random seek time, not read write throughput, because database operations are many small reads/writes, not continuous streaming.

Solid state drives are another option to look for, but if you're wanting 15K inserts per second or more, they might be too slow. SSDs should scream for reads, though.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually the I/O operations that are costly. By I/O I mean the data read and written to hard drives. I suggest that besides RAM, invest on higher RPM hard drive (or drives and set them up as performance RAID devices).

EDIT ----

There is RAID setup for performance, RAID setup for fault tolerance and RAID setup for both. For 2 drives, RAID 0 and RAID 1 are the available options, RAID 0 being the faster one.

Comment: So what's the one that does both? I think I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to improve performance of your inserts, I recommend investing on hard drives besides processor and RAM. If you can invest on two hard drives, I additionally suggest you look at possibility to configure them as RAID.

Higher levels of RAID provide fault tolerance (against hard drive failure) and performance but they require at-least 3 hard drives. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels